# Работа с web в C++

Tags: веб-программирование, c++

Доброго времени суток! Меня интересуют библиотеки на *C++*, позволяющие работать с *web*-страницами(конкретно мне нужны способы импорта *Google Docs*, получение исходного кода страницы, ввод данных в *submit*-поля). Что можно найти по этому вопросу?

Comment: а почему бы вам не использовать более подходящий для таких целей язык? Преимущества С++ вроде скорости выполнения в случае с web стираются, поскольку узкое место в плане производительности - это общение клиента с сервером, и никакой С++ не поможет это ускорить. А вот головной боли получите предостаточно

Comment: @DreamChild я пишу простое приложение для личных целей, а других языков я не знаю

Comment: @aapetrov3 вообще для каждой задачи разумно  выбирать свой инструмент. Для разработки веб-приложений С++, пожалуй, не самый лучший выбор в силу ряда причин. Впрочем, если нужен именно С++, то можете почитать [вот этот цикл статей][1], недавно опубликованный на Хабре, возможно, найдете там что-то полезное (впрочем, не ручаюсь, сам не читал)

Comment: начните с классических библиотек, например [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). Она точно решит проблему получения исходного кода страницы и "ввода данных в submit поля" (на самом деле ничего не нужно вводить, нужно просто сформировать правильный запрос).